# How can I improve the look for my responsive nav in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made this div responsive in Bootstrap. But, the styling and formatting doesn't look quite right. When you click on the expand button, I feel like the "Sign Up" and "Login" sections should be in a separate section from the blue and the lines look messed up. How can I make this nav look more responsive and professional?

```css
.navbar {
  background: #007BC4 !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.nav a {
  color: white !important;
}

#sign_up {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#email_form, #password_form {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #007BC4;
}

#login_button {
  background: #0092ea !important;
  border: 1px solid #005c93;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

#login_button:hover {
  background: #007BC4 !important;
}

#remember_label {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#forgot_password {
  color: white !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 13px !important;
}

#remember {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand{
 height:auto;
 padding: 0px 15px;
}
.navbar-brand img{ max-width:250px;width:100%;}
.navbar-nav > li > a{padding-top: 0;}
@media (max-width:1000px) {
 .navbar-header {
     float: left;
  width:25%;
 }
 .navbar-brand{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px; 
  padding:0;
 }
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
 .navbar-header {
     float: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
 }
 .navbar-brand{
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
 .navbar-brand img {
     max-width: 200px;
 }
 .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 7.5px 0;
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding: 10px 0;
 }
 .navbar-form{
  float: left;
 }
 #sign_up {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0px;
 }
 #email_form, #password_form{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #login_button{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
            </a>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- Sign Up -->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li> <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id='sign_up'> Sign Up </button></a> </li>
            </ul>
   <!-- Login -->
   <div class='navbar-form navbar-right'>
     <form action='#' method='post'>
       <input type='text' placeholder='Email' id='email_form'>
       <input type='text' placeholder='Password' type='password' id='password_form'>
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id='login_button'>Login</button>
     </form>
     
     <input type='checkbox' name='remember' id='remember'> <label for='remember' id='remember_label'> Remember me </label>
     
     <a href='#' id='forgot_password'> Forgot Password? </a>
     
   </div>
   
  </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- JS Files -->
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean like making your button responsive? if your using css, i'm guessing you know html right? make a link. thats what i'm suggesting. and to make it look professional, you basically just have to rely on gut instinct. (colors dude, what colors are professional anyway, beige?)

Comment: Ok, minimize the screen and expand the nav. Do you see the lines that surround both the Login & Sign Up? I want to clean up those lines and also change the bg color of the section. It doesn't feel professional to me :)